# How to style ASP.Net charts in MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, charts, data-visualization

There is a basic HTML helper for generating charts in .NET, but it does not allow to specify some basic styling, position of the legend and things like that. Alternative is to generate chart in a controller using old DataVisualization.Charting namespace, but this is too hacky. I don't understand why MVC 3 does not address this issue? The charts are too basic.

THank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to use MSCharts that were originally written for web forms. Servlets should generate chart images and serve them to calling views. This has been explained in: [Charting in ASP.Net MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281520/asp-net-mvc-3-chart-web-helper-no-documentation)

Answer (score 2):

The correct way is to use XML.

See here

http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/03/21/chart-helper-in-asp-net-mvc-3-0-with-transparent-background.aspx