# Are there any reporting tools that provide an MVC 3 ReportViewer for the Razor ViewEngine out of the box?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, reporting

As stated in the title. Most of what I've seen involve workarounds to get their native Webforms report viewers into the MVC workspace and fewer innately support the Razor ViewEngine. Are there any, free or paid, that provide this?

I'm looking for ones similar to how the default Webforms ReportViewer handles things where you get a preview of what you're about to export.

Comment: Have a look at  this post : http://stackoverflow.com/a/6283306/971693 It should answer your question.

Comment: Edited to add a few more details on what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

Personally i use [Perpetuum SharpShooter](http://www.perpetuumsoft.com/SharpShooter-Reports-Web.aspx) for web reporting. I work with standard ASP.NET WebForms, but I saw somewhere the documentation for Razor.

However Unfortunately, it doesn not have native web-based report designer. It's a pitty. I have to create huge workarounds to provide my users with their windows report editor.