# Charting in MVC 4

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, charts

I have been searching for quite a while and have not been able to find what I am looking for.

I want to generate a chart in my controller and serve it to my view via a ViewModel. The two most useful articles I found are

http://www.codecapers.com/post/Build-a-Dashboard-With-Microsoft-Chart-Controls.aspx#tb

[Charting in ASP.Net MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281520/charting-in-asp-net-mvc-3)

Both show you how to create the chart object, but they don't help me display it in the view in a way I desire. I understand you can save the image and simply open the image from your view, but what if I desire the chart to be interactive? Perhaps going to a another page when clicking a slice on a pie chart, or other useful "drill down" functionality.

Am I confused? Is this sort of functionality possible with pure asp.net mvc, or am I confusing the fancy features with a 3rd party charting library? If the former, how do I render my chart object `public Chart queueChart { get; set; }` in my view?

And just as a note, I am not interested in using a 3rd party charting library.

Controller:

```
//Query from db into model.queue
Chart chart = new Chart();
chart.Width = 600;
chart.Height = 400;
chart.Titles.Add("Title goes here");
chart.ChartAreas.Add(new ChartArea());
Series series = new Series();

series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie;

foreach( Queue i in model.queue )
{
    string x = i.name;
    double y = i.count;

    series.Points.AddXY(x, y);
}

chart.Series.Add(series);

model.queueChart = chart;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456772.aspx) describes how to enable interactivity in the Chart control using client-side image maps.

Googling "MVC3 image maps chart" will locate some resources.

Answer (score 7):

Why not use a JavaScript library that does charting? These will offer lots of functionality and allow you to have interactive charts.

[HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com)

[KendoUI](http://www.kendoui.com/dataviz.aspx)

Comment: I had considered it, but the company I am working for likes to be very secure. They limit the software (and libraries) we are allowed to use. There are no approved charting libraries, but we are allowed to use anything under the MVC umbrella, which is why I choose to use the .NET implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider a Javascript library if you want interactivity.
[jqChart](http://www.jqchart.com/) is a powerful and yet simple to use library based on jQuery and they also provide an MVC version.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to making charts interactive, the best way would be using high charts. These are very user friendly and not to mention the fact that they are the most interactive unit, along with all the drill down features. Trust me or not but you'd want to check it out before concluding anything. 
Check out the link it has all the instructions along with an example.

https://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com/

Make sure to install the package : Dotnet.HighCharts

This can be done by
TOOLS->Library Package Manager->Package Manager Console..

PM>Install-Package DotNet.HighCharts

Then in the view make sure to drag the script files (/jquery-1.5.1.min.js and /highcharts.js).
Thus creating a reference. ( IN MVC )
Along with

@model DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts

@(Model)